# Need to sort NaN in Python to the end of a list

Tags: python, list, sorting, nan

I'm trying to sort a list and work around Python's poor handling of `nan` and `inf`.

I need to partition a list into all the numbers sorted (or reversed) and at the end of the list any NaN or Inf. The order of the non-number (NaN/Inf) elements is not important, so long as they are arranged at the end of the list.

For example:

```py
n = [13, 4, 52, 3.1, float('nan'), float('inf'), 8.2]
print(n)
o = sorted(n, key = lambda x : float('inf') if (x != x) else x)
print(o)
print(reversed(o))
```

The `o` works, and outputs:

```
[3.1, 4, 8.2, 13, 52, nan, inf]
```

But using `reversed` outputs:

```
[inf, nan, 52, 13, 8.2, 4, 3.1]
```

Which is not what I want.

I want it to reverse only the values that aren't `nan` and `inf`.

Desired output:

```
[52, 13, 8.2, 4, 3.1, nan, inf]
```

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks, I've clarified the partitioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sorted` with `math.isinf` and `math.isnan` to detect whether it the value either is `nan` or `inf`. If they are real numerical values, I negate them for reversing their order.

Example:

```
import math
n = [13, 4, 52, 3.1, float('nan'), float('inf'), 8.2]
lst = sorted(n, key=lambda x: (math.isinf(x) or math.isnan(x), -x))
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[52, 13, 8.2, 4, 3.1, nan, inf]
```

---

If you don't want to `reverse` the values:

```
print(sorted(n))
```

Is enough.

Output:

```
[3.1, 4, 8.2, 13, 52, nan, inf]
```

Comment: Note that a naive `sorted` is not enough if `nan` is involved. Try `sorted(n[::-1])` for a quick example; the `nan` "partitions" the list during sorting. The issue is that `sorted` considers a number "done" once it compares to another as expected, and since `nan` does not compare as expected this breaks things. Whether `sorted` gives the expected result depends on the initial position of `nan`.